# UIImageView does not load image from URL iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have imageView i want to load image from url but it is not loading i am using following code

```
               pdfView.hidden=NO;
       webView.hidden=NO;
       pictureImageView.hidden=NO;
      pdfView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
      doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@" Done " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneButtonClick)];            
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =doneButton;
      webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


        NSLog(@"File Name is %@",fileName);

        NSLog(@"Enterning in the ImageSection");

        NSString *ImageURL = fileName;
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
            pictureImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Instead of this if i want to give from local like below then also it does not show image in imageView any idea how to load image from url thank

```
        pictureImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"starblue.png"];
```

Comment: imageUrl contains image?

Comment: have you given a frame to pictureImageView ??

Comment: bad code formatting..

Comment: @LithT.V yes imageURl contains img path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set frame of that image and then write this line after add image in `pictureImageView`

```
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pictureImageView];
```

Comment: i have added pictureImageView from IB

Comment: yes but may be some view you add on it and thats bringups on view and your pictureimageview not displayed so first set frame properly after add any image in this UIImage which is available in your project and add my above line and then let me know what you get... :) i hope its useful to you...

Comment: thanks it worked basically i had not connected outlet by mistake thanks it worked

Comment: i wanted to ask some thing i have imageView with two buttons in it Add Feedback and Library i want that when i click on button inside cell it should point to the selected cell so for this how to get the cell current position

Comment: what you mean exactly dude??

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine

Things to check

1. Url contain a valid image
2. Set ImageView  alloc it properly set frame and then add image

`UIImageView *pictureImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 50, 50)];`
Then do the rest

This is synchronous image loading that will block the main thread activities.Prefer to use asynchronous image download using AFNetworking or AsynchImageview

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for show image in Url .

```
  NSString *image=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your URL"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
  NSLog(@"%@",image);
  NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]];
 Yourimageview=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 pictureImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgurl]]];
```